# Deleting a vector of 2d arrays

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, vector

I have this vector:

```
std::vector<int**> vec;
```

I fill this vector with 2d matrices with a size `size x size` allocated with `new` (I checked the values in matrices saved in the vector, they're correct)

```
    matrix = new int*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        matrix[i] = new int[size];

    /*here I add some values to the array and save it to the vector
     *
     *
     */
    vec.push_back(matrix);

    /* this I do with several matrices
```

then I want to delete matrices in the vector and erase the vector to the zero length.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
            delete[] vec[i][j];
        delete[] vec[i];
        }
    }
    if (vec.size() > 0)
        vec.erase(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

The deletion cause this error:

```
double free or corruption (fasttop):
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: I do not fully understand it but I find [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/31363/#msg169817) interesting when you want to delete particular columns or rows of a vector in c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `delete[] vec[i]` is inside the inner for loop.

Here is, how it should look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
        delete[] vec[i][j];
    }
    delete[] vec[i];
}
vec.clear()
```

Comment: I forgot to change `boardMatrices` to `vec` I'm sorry, I edited it yet. And as you can see I call delete as many times as new, I think. I need to use arrays instead of vectors.

Comment: You could use `vector<vector<vector<int> > >`. Or you could use some matrix library like Eigen.